# CollectionView with different item sizes not working on Iphone 6plus

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, iphone-6-plus

I'm trying to create a collectionview of Images with items in different sizes. In that collectionview, I want 2 items (one bigger, one smaller) to fill one screen row. What I wrote is

```
itemWith = (collectionviewWidth) / 2.69;
smallerSize = CGSizeMake(itemWith, itemWith * 1.3);
biggerSize = CGSizeMake(itemWith * 1.69, itemWith * 1.3);
```

I've already use UICollectionViewFlowLayout to make sure there is no space between items, like following

```
setMinimumInteritemSpacing = 0
setMinimumLineSpacing = 0
return UIEdgeInsetsZero on method "insetForSectionAtIndex"
```

This layout works perfectly on Iphone 5 & Iphone 6, each 2 items will fill one row and so on. But when I run on iphone6plus, the second item was push into the next row.

I guess the reason is 6plus comes with Rendered Pixels 3x while iphone 5 & 6 comes with 2x. But I'm not sure and have no idea about how to fix it as well. Anyone can help me explain it and show me the way to make my layout work correctly on all kind of devices. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

You should do all calculs for the size of you `UICollectionViewCell`'s in the delegate method :

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Also, you may need to use `autolayout` instead of setting the frame by hand: the larger screen estate of the 6 plus would have been taken care of by it.